# prolog misunderstanding. Split list into two list with even and odd positions. where is my mistake?

Tags: list, split, prolog

I'm trying to split a list into two other list. List Even with the elemnts in even possition and a List Odd with the others. I've been looking over iinternet a solution, but all seem to me like chinese, i can not understand the process.  So this is what i've been trying:

```
split(List,Odd,Even):-odd(List,Oddlist,Evenlist).

odd([H|T],Oddlist,Evenlist):-even(T,[H|Oddlist],Evenlist).
odd([],_,_).

even([H|T],Oddlist,Evenlist):-odd(T,Oddlist,[H|Evenlist]).       
even([],_,_).
```

but the only return i got is something like Oddlist = _7132946  Evenlist = _26997888.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong.  I'll apreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: For sure you got a warning for the rule `split/3`! Take such warnings as errors! (There is more, but this is just the start.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by CapelliC is perfect. Just to explain:

When you have a Prolog clause like this:

```
foo([H|T], [H|Z]) :-
    foo(T, Z).
```

which you then call like this:

```
?- foo([a,b,c], L).
from: foo([H|  T  ], [H|Z]) with H = a, T = [b,c], L = [a|Z]
call: foo([a|[b,c]], [a|Z])
```

which then leads to the recursive call:

```
call: foo([b,c], Z).
from: foo([H|  T  ], [H|Z]) with H = b, T = [c], L = [b|Z]
call: foo([b|[c]], [b|Z])
```

At this point, the list that you made at the beginning, `[a|Z]` is now `[a|[b|Z]]`, which is `[a,b|Z]`.

So, you create a list in the variable passed as the second argument, and stick *H* at the front of the list. The rest of the list you give to the recursive call. You will keep adding elements to the end of the list until the first list is the empty list. At that point, you will have end the new list, too:

```
foo([], []).
```

In your example, there is another predicate mutually recursive with the first one:

```
foo([], [], []).
foo([H|T], [H|F], B) :-
    bar(T, F, B).

bar([], [], []).
bar([H|T], F, [H|B]) :-
    foo(T, F, B).
```

Of course, this will "unzip" a list into two lists.

Comment: So... If I'm undertanding in the right way, when I create a List passed as the secnd argument, and put a Head in the front of that list, the tail of the list go to some kind of "limbo zone", and wait there for the recursion to bring it back... so thats why in some point I get the ([],[]) for the base. I think...  sorry, this is very hard for me.

Comment: @Peyu Not a "limbo zone" exactly; what happens to it is very well defined. This is why I tried to give you this explanation: so that you can see how the second list is actually made.

Comment: After a few hours of good sleep, I see it much better now. In your example, the second list is in the begginning  [a|Z], next step is [b|Z2] next step [c|Z3] and then just []  ...  so Z=  a|Z2,  Z2= b|Z3  Z3= c then reconstruct Z=[a,b,c]  and thats the answer!!   Am I right?? THANK YOU SO MUCHH!!

Answer (score 3):

Your idea must be refined...

First, every language (not only Prolog) needs that symbols are named consistently. So I've renamed the variables as needed.

Specific to Prolog, there is a particular way to 'cons' lists, derived from the pattern matching applied on rule heads. The same applies to the base cases: we must provide the empty lists that will bind the variables in callers.

The whole code:

```
split(List,Odd,Even):-odd(List,Odd,Even).

odd([H|T],[H|Odd],Even):-even(T,Odd,Even).
odd([],[],[]).

even([H|T],Odd,[H|Even]):-odd(T,Odd,Even).       
even([],[],[]).
```

Comment: Wow... that works perfect! But I don't understand why the base is odd([],[],[]).   I mean, if I try split([1,2,3],E,O).  and follow the flow step by step, i got a even([],[1,3],[2]).  as  a last state...  how it becomes even([],[],[]).?

Comment: the recursive calls pass down the *tail* of the list, so the base case is *identified* by the empty list. Try to `:- trace.` an execution...

Answer (score 1):

I understand this post is rather old now but I figured I would add my solution as well, so if there is someone like I was 15 mins ago, they have something else to look at. This way builds the lists up backwards in way to create the final lists. First 3 lines are the base cases.

```
    split_odd_even([], [], []).
    split_odd_even([O], [O], []).
    split_odd_even([O,E], [O], [E]).
    split_odd_even([O,E|T], [O|OL], [E|EL]) :- split_odd_even(T, OL, EL).
```